# How to make Tramp execute only if address is reachable?

Tags: tramp

So I have a couple of VM I'm using (*mainly for experiment*) I use Tramp a lot on a particular file in the VM, so I started to use this:

```lisp
(find-file "/ssh:vm@192.168.122.141:/home/vm/test.org" t)
```

I put that in my init file, so it always connects when I launch emacs... except that most of the time, I didn't plan on using the vm, so it cannot connect to it (*since the vm isn't opened before emacs is launched*) emacs stop halfway in loading the init file.

So how could i make it so the aforementioned line of elisp would only open the file if the address is reachable?

Comment: Try (file-exists-p “/ssh:vm@...”) to see if it returns a more timely negative result.

Comment: I'd use a sync utility for that kind of task, either syncthing or a croned task.

Comment: Elisp tag doesn't apply here. Please read [Elisp tag info](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info)

Comment: prefer to not use sync or sync the file, as i only sync it when i need to :) (it's mostly to save space, since it's already in the vm anyway) @Muihlinn

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this @InHarmsWay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, isn't a great idea opening remote files from your init
files. I'd use bookmarks or whatever else to open them quickly when
needed, also, I'd rather use any sync service like *syncthing* or a `rsync` cron task to keep them synced if, as you seem to suggest, the file also lies elsewhere.

If you **absolutelly** need to do it, I'd check if the server is up using
something like this (*assuming you're on some kind of un*x*):

```lisp
(let ((out (shell-command-to-string "nc -v -z -W 2 192.168.122.141 22")))
  (if (string-match "succeeded" out 0)
    (find-file "/ssh:vm@192.168.122.141:/home/vm/test.org" t)
    (message "server down")))
```

While probably there is a pure elisp way to do it, I'd prefer calling `nc` because is straightforward, usually comes installed by default and there are plenty of examples of its use. In this case `-W` specifies the timeout.